# Can't change highlighted text color of custom QListView rows

Tags: qt, pyside, osx-yosemite, qlistview

For some strange reason cannot override a highlighted text colour in `QListView`. It worked fine (a highlighted text colour is auto-changed to white) until I defined my own widget to represent a row.

Now I can change background colour and some other visual aspects of a selected row, but text colour always remains default black.

Already tried all possible with `QSS`, `QPalette` and `data()`/`Qt.ForegroundRole` - no trick helps.

Here is a simplified code, which still suffers from the issue on `OS X`. Unfortunately I had no chance to test on `Windows` or `GNU/Linux`.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

view = None
mapp = {}

style = '''
QListView {
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    selection-color: white;
    selection-background-color: #0068d9;
}

QListView::item:selected:active:hover{
    background-color:red; color: white;
}
QListView::item:selected:active:!hover{
    background-color: #0068d9; color: white;
}
QListView::item:selected:!active{
    background-color:yellow; color: white;
}
QListView::item:!selected:hover{
    background-color:green; color: white;
}
'''

class SimpleListModel(QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, mlist):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self._items = mlist

    def rowCount(self, parent = QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        node = self._items[row]

        if not(str(row) in mapp):
            index = self.createIndex(row, column)
            widget = QLabel(node)
            view.setIndexWidget(index, widget)
            mapp[str(row)] = index
            return index

        return mapp[str(row)]

    def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled    

class MyMainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        global view
        QWidget.__init__(self, None)

        self._model = SimpleListModel(["test", "tes1t", "t3est", "t5est", "t3est"])

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        view = QListView()
        view.setModel(self._model)
        vbox.addWidget(view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        view.setStyleSheet(style)

        first = self._model.index(0, 0)
        view.setCurrentIndex(first)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyMainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Just let me know if I understood correctly. You want to change the text color of the selected row and the others to remain the same? If this is what you want, please check my answer below. Not the best solution but I'm quite in a hurry right now. If needed I can clean it up a bit in the next days...it's Easter after all :)

Comment: Yes, your solution is exactly what I needed. Well, I expected to see an overlooked in the docs "killer CSS selector", which solves the problem the most elegant way. But obviously there is no pure CSS solution and your approach in the case is quite good. Thank you! The bounty is yours.

Answer (score 4):

Not the cleanest or best solution but this is what I came with after some tweaking.

Result:

[image]

The blue item is the selected one. The green item is the hovered one.

Code:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

view = None
mapp = {}

style = '''
QListView {
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    selection-color: white;
    selection-background-color: #0068d9;
}

QListView::item:selected:active:hover{
    background-color:red; color: white;
}
QListView::item:selected:active:!hover{
    background-color: #0068d9; color: white;
}
QListView::item:selected:!active{
    background-color:yellow; color: white;
}
QListView::item:!selected:hover{
    background-color:green; color: white;
}
'''

class SimpleListModel(QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, mlist):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self._items = mlist

    def rowCount(self, parent = QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        node = self._items[row]

        if not(str(row) in mapp):
            index = self.createIndex(row, column)
            widget = QLabel(node)
            view.setIndexWidget(index, widget)

            mapp[str(row)] = index
            return index


        return mapp[str(row)]

    def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
        # The following code shouldn't be put in this function but i'm in a hurry right now...
        selectedIndexes = view.selectedIndexes()

        # Set all items to black
        for i in range(0, self.rowCount()):
            currentRowIndex = self.index(i, 0, QModelIndex())
            myWidget = view.indexWidget(currentRowIndex)
            myWidget.setStyleSheet("color: black")

        # Set selected items to white
        for i in selectedIndexes:
            myWidget = view.indexWidget(i)
            myWidget.setStyleSheet("color: white")

        return None

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled    

class MyMainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        global view
        QWidget.__init__(self, None)

        self._model = SimpleListModel(["test", "tes1t", "t3est", "t5est", "t3est"])

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        view = QListView()
        view.setModel(self._model)
        vbox.addWidget(view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        view.setStyleSheet(style)

        first = self._model.index(0, 0)
        view.setCurrentIndex(first)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyMainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Please let me know if there's something I didn't understand correctly or the code is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

First:
Your code is working on GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, PyQt5) in the same way.

Since text is written to `indexWidget`, stylesheet for the `text-color` must be set for `QLabel`.

As `QLabel` does not support the hover pseudostate, it can not be done in the same way as for the items.

To set stylesheet for selected `indexWidgets` I used signal-slot-mechanism, for hovered `indexWidgets` I used event filter,

[image]

only class MyMainWindow modified:

```
class MyMainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        global view
        QWidget.__init__(self, None)

        self._model = SimpleListModel(["test", "tes1t", "t3est", "t5est", "t3est"])

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        view = QListView()
        view.setModel(self._model)
        view.setMouseTracking(True)         # to catch mouseEvents
        view.installEventFilter(self)           # for events in ListView 
        vbox.addWidget(view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        view.setStyleSheet(style)

        first = self._model.index(0, 0)
        view.setCurrentIndex(first)
        view.clicked.connect(self.setIndexStyle)    # or any other signal

    def setIndexStyle(self, index):
        for i in range(0,view.model().rowCount()):
            style = 'color: black;'
            view.indexWidget(view.model().index(i,0)).setStyleSheet(style)
        for i in view.selectedIndexes():    # works for multiseletion too
            style = 'color: white;'
            view.indexWidget(i).setStyleSheet(style)

    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.HoverMove and isinstance(obj,QListView):
            i =  view.indexAt(event.pos())      # index at mouse.pos()
            self.setIndexStyle(i)       # selected indexWidgets still have white text
            style = 'color: white;'
            try:                # if no item on mouse.pos()
                view.indexWidget(i).setStyleSheet(style)
            except AttributeError:      
                pass
            return False
        return QWidget.eventFilter(self,obj,event)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! luliu was the first with an acceptable solution, so the bounty went to him. I really appreciate your help!